# Create custom XML which is then picked up via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, ajax

For some reason, I keep getting XMLDoc is null, in firebug. I think that perhaps my program isn't parsing the XML that I am trying to generate (and that means I am likely not doing it correctly).

NOTE: I DO NOT WANT TO USE JQUERY HERE!

Here's my code that is supposed to generate the XML code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("generic");
$rescult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM culture order by cult_id");
if (!$rescult) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rescult);
ECHO "<item>";
ECHO "<item1>" . $row[0] . "</item1>" . "<br />";
ECHO "<item2>" . $row[1] . "</item2>" . "<br />";
ECHO "</item>";
?>
```

And here's my code that is supposed to parse it:

```
<html>
<header>
<script type="text/javascript">

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{   // Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{   
    // Code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","testitout2.php",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("item1").value =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

document.getElementById("item2").value =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item2")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

</script>
</header>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="item1">
        <input type="text" id="item2">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Requests made to the server are asynchronous. You won't get the response immediately, as your code expects. Instead, you have to set up a handler for the state changes of the request, and you'll get the data when it's returned to the client from the server.

Comment: What do get if you do `xmlhtp.responseText` in Firebug console after the request has completed?

Comment: @Pointy: as the flag `async` is explicitly set to `false` in the OP's code, the request *is* synchronous.

Comment: Oh durr, you're right, @Luc1245 - well he shouldn't do that anyway :-)

Comment: @Pointy I totally agree... Ajax is meant to be asynchronous, otherwise it is not Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I didn't notice the `async` flag. Guess my answer is irrelevant then.

You are trying to access XML before it was even loaded.
Set property `onreadystatechange` to `xmlhttp`:

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = onStateChange;

 function onStateChange() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return; //4 means doc is ready
    var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong HTML tag: `<header>...</header>`.

Try replacing it with `<head>...</head>`, otherwise your script might be simply skipped by the browser.